# Count down from "Infinity"

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, counting

Seems like an impossible task right? Well, it's actually not that hard. If we write the word `Infinity` as 8-bit binary ASCII code, we'll get:

```
01001001 01101110 01100110 01101001 01101110 01101001 01110100 01111001
```

This can be concatenated, and converted to the decimal value `5291279215216915577`. Now that's a number we can work with...

The way you'll count down is:

1. Output the original string as a decimal number (as shown above)
2. Remove leading 0s in its binary representation (if any)
3. Toggle the bits in the binary representation (1->0, 0->1)
4. Output the number in decimal
5. Repeat steps 2-4 as until you reach 0.

**Challenge:**

Create a program or function that takes a string as input, and outputs (on any suitable format) the numbers you'll get when performing the procedure above.

**Test case:**

I think the challenge will be fairly easy to understand, even though it's only one test case. I'll use `Inf` instead of `Infinity` to keep this fairly short.

```
Inf
4812390  (10010010110111001100110)
3576217  ( 1101101001000110011001)
618086   (   10010110111001100110)
430489   (    1101001000110011001)
93798    (      10110111001100110)
37273    (       1001000110011001)
28262    (        110111001100110)
4505     (          1000110011001)
3686     (           111001100110)
409      (              110011001)
102      (                1100110)
25       (                  11001)
6        (                    110)
1        (                      1)
0        (                      0)
```

```
Input: Inf 
Output:
4812390, 3576217, 618086, 430489, 93798, 37273, 28262, 4505, 3686, 409, 102, 25, 6, 1, 0
```

```
Input: Infinity
Output:
5291279215216915577, 3932092821637860230, 679593196789527673, 473328307817319302, 103132444486104185, 40982743589751686, 31074850448176249, 4953946570787718, 4053252683953273, 450346943417222, 112603010004089, 28134478351238, 7049893737593, 1746199284614, 452823970937, 96931842950, 40507110521, 28212366214, 6147372153, 2442562438, 1852404857, 295078790, 241792121, 26643334, 6911097, 1477510, 619641, 428934, 95353, 35718, 29817, 2950, 1145, 902, 121, 6, 1, 0
```

Your code must support strings that can be represented as a binary number up to the limit of your language. All strings will only contain printable ASCII-characters from 32-126 (space to tilde).

---

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=98274,OVERRIDE_USER=31516;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Chuck Norris](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/node/167051), 8 bytes: `Inf:-1:0`

Comment: @LuisMendo Chuck Norris' NARS-APL: `∞..0`

Comment: @LuisMendo Are you sure you don't mean [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/285610)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-5 bytes thanks to @Dennis (convert directly from base 256 after ordinal cast)

```
Oḅ⁹µBCḄµÐĿ
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T-G4heKBucK1QkPhuITCtcOQxL8&input=&args=QW4gZXhhbXBsZSB3aXRoIDYzIGRpZ2l0cyE)**

#### How?

```
Oḅ⁹µBCḄµÐĿ - Main link: s                     e.g. "Inf"
O          - cast to ordinals                 e.g. [73,110,102]
 ḅ⁹        - convert from base 256 to integer e.g. 4812390
   µ   µ   - monadic chain separations
    B      -     convert to binary
     C     -     complement
      Ḅ    -     convert to integer
        ÐĿ - loop until no longer unique and collect results
```

Comment: The first part is just `Oḅ⁹`.

Comment: Oh my, how did I miss that?!

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>89</s> <s>82</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 75 bytes

```python
n=0
for c in input():n=n<<8|ord(c)
while 1:print n;n^=2**n.bit_length()-n/n
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/1aiYcE).

#### How it works

After initializing **n** to **0**, the second line performs the string-to-integer conversion specified in the challenges as follows.

In each step, **n** is shifted **8** units to the left, then bitwise **OR**-ed with the the code point of the next character **c**. For input **Inf**, this goes as follows.

```
n                                  0
a = n<<8                           0
b = 'I'                      1001001
n = a ^ b                    1001001
a = n<<8             100100100000000
b = 'n'                      1101110
n = a ^ b            100100101101110
a = n<<8     10010010110111000000000
b = 'f'                      1100110
n = a ^ b    10010010110111001100110
```

Now we're ready to generate the output. To invert the bits of **n**, we proceed as follows.

First, we compute the bits in **n**'s binary representation without leading zeroes. Let's call the result **k**. Then, we compute the **k**<sup>k</sup> power of **2**, which has **k+1** binary digits: a single **1**, followed by **k** **0**'s. We subtract **1** from the result, yielding a number composed of **k** ones, which we then XOR with **n** to invert its bits. For input **inf** this goes as follows.

```
n         4812390   10010010110111001100110
k              23 
t = 2**k           100000000000000000000000
t -= 1              11111111111111111111111
n ^= t    3576217    1101101001000110011001
k              22
t = 2**k            10000000000000000000000
t -= 1               1111111111111111111111
n ^= t     618086      10010110111001100110
.
.
.
n               6                       110
k               3
t = 2**k                               1000
t -= 1                                  111
n ^= t          1                         1
k               1
t = 2**k                                 10
t -= 1                                    1
n ^= t          0                         0
```

On additional hurdle in the implementation is that we have to print **n** before the first step, *after* the last step, and in all steps in between. Python doesn't have do-while loops and a single *print* statement costs **8** bytes, so we do the following instead.

In the straightforward implementation of the update step, i.e.,

```python
while n:print n;n^=2**n.bit_length()-1
print n
```

we replace the loop with an infinite one (`while 1`) and compute the `1` in the loop as `n/n`. This is equivalent while **n > 0**.

Once **n = 0**, we stay in the loop, print the state once more, then try to update it. However, `0/0` triggers a *ZeroDivisionError*, breaking out of the loop and exiting with an error. Note that this causes stray output to STDERR, which is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/12012).

Comment: I love that `-n/n` trick :-)

Comment: Can you explain than `n/n` trick? It's probably been explained in another answer somewhere but I haven't found it. What does it do here?

Comment: @StewieGriffin n/n is 1 until n is 0, then it throws an error and causes the program to stop.

Comment: With an error message (I hope)?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Indeed. Python is *painfully* verbose when it comes to error reporting. I've edited my answer to incorporate an explanation.

Comment: Nice explanation... Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, 82 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Arnuald*

```js
for(y of prompt(n=0))n=n<<8|y.charCodeAt()
for(;alert(n)|n;)for(i=1;i<=n;i*=2)n^=i
```

One of the very few times when a full program outperforms a function (and ES6 does not outperform ES5)...

---

The above supports up to 4-letter words. Add 4 bytes to support up to 6-letter words:

```js
for(y of prompt(n=0))n=n*256+y.charCodeAt()
for(;alert(n)|n;n=i-n-1)for(i=1;i<=n;)i*=2
```

Comment: `g=a=>a[0]?a.pop().charCodeAt()+g(a)*256:0` (-1)

Comment: @Titus Thanks! Not sure why I didn't think of that

Comment: `n<<8|y.charCodeAt()` should save a byte. `for(;n;)for(i=!alert(n);i<=n;i*=2)n^=i` would save another byte, but you won't display `0`, which is probably required.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks. I thought about doing `n<<8` earlier but decided it wouldn't work because it would break for n with more than 31 bits. I suppose it doesn't matter now that I've already split it between a 31-bit version and a 53-bit version... And sadly, I don't think I can save anything on the alert while alerting both the first iteration and the last.

Answer (score 7):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 14 bytes

```
2@├¿W■├♂≈♂Y2@¿
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=MkDilJzCv1filqDilJzimYLiiYjimYJZMkDCvw&input=IkluZiI)

Explanation:

```
2@├¿W■├♂≈♂Y2@¿
 @├             encode input in binary
2  ¿            convert from binary to decimal
    W           while the number is not 0:
     ■            print the number without popping
      ├           convert number to binary
       ♂≈         convert each character to an int
         ♂Y       boolean negate each int
           2@¿    convert from binary to decimal
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

Uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
Çžz+b€¦J[CÐ,_#bS_J
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4fFvnorYuKCrMKmSltDw5AsXyNiU19K&input=SW5m)

**Explanation**

```
Ç                     # convert string to list of ascii codes
 žz+                  # add 256 to each
    b                 # convert to binary
     €¦               # remove the first digit of each list of digits
       J              # join
        [             # start loop
         C            # convert to decimal
          Ð           # triplicate
           ,          # print 1 copy
            _#        # if the 2nd copy is 0, break loop
              b       # convert 3rd copy to binary
               S      # split to list
                _     # negate each in list
                 J    # join
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>132</s> <s>126</s> <s>123</s> <s>120</s> <s>108</s> 107 bytes

```
foreach(unpack("C*",$argv[1])as$i)$n=$n*256+$i;for(print$n;$n;)echo _.$n=bindec(strtr(decbin($n),"01",10));
```

- printing 0 after loop instead of initial value before loop saves 6 bytes.
- `unpack` instead of `str_split` renders `ord()` obsolete -> -3 bytes
- underscore `_` as separator saves 3.
- `bindec` instead of `ltrim` to remove leading zeroes: -12
- `echo` in loop body saves 1 byte over `print` in loop head.

Comment: Can't `$n=$n*256+$i;for(print$n;$n;)` be written as `for(print$n=$n*256+$i;$n;)`? Since the assignment part will execute once, this should work. And instead of  `echo _.$n=[...]`, you should use `echo _,$n=[...]` instead. It won't save any byte, but will speed the code a **tiny tiny tiny tiny** bit and will separate statements. That means that, for example, `echo _,$a?5:6;` can be written instead of `echo _.($a?5:6);`. This may be helpful in the future.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The assignment part is a loop. I actually use the comma when I don´t need the dot; it is a remnant from the `print` in this case. Alone not worth an edit; but thanks.

Comment: Oh, right... It is inside the `foreach(unpack("C*",$argv[1])as$i)`... Silly me... And yes, changing a period for a comma to have the same effect isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
8W:qZA`tB~XBt
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OFc6cVpBYHRCflhCdA&input=J0luZic)

#### Explanation

```
8W:q            % Push array [0 1 ... 255]
    ZA          % Take input string and convert it from the base defined by the
                % alphabet [0 1 ... 255] to decimal
      `         % Do...while
       t        % Duplicate
        B       % Convert to binary
         ~      % Negate
          XB    % Convert to decimal
            t   % Duplicate. Used as loop condition: exit if zero
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 99 bytes

```
a=FromDigits;b=IntegerDigits;NestWhileList[a[1-#~b~2,2]&,a[Join@@b[ToCharacterCode@#,2,8],2],#>0&]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string as input, and returns a list of numbers as output.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>109</s> <s>123</s> <s>118</s> <s>102</s> 97 bytes

Thanks to @nimi for saving 5 bytes!

```
c 0=0
c n=1-mod n 2+2*c(div n 2)
(++[0]).fst.span(>0).iterate c.foldl((+).(256*))0.map fromEnum
```

Usage: `(++[0]).fst.span(>0).iterate c.foldl((+).(256*))0.map fromEnum $ "Infinity"`

Guaranteed to work on numbers up to 29 bits by the language, usually works up to 63-bit numbers on 64-bit systems. Use `map(fromIntegral.fromEnum)` instead (+14 bytes) to support arbitrarily large numbers.

Works for unicode range `[0..255]`. Recursively flips bits.

Comment: You can replace `takeWhile(>0)` with `fst.span(>0)`. If you go pointfree you can drop the name `f`, so your main function is `(++[0]) ... map fromEnum`.

Comment: @nimi thanks, dropping the name solves the type inference problem I had with `f`.

Comment: Why `fromIntegral`? From the challenge: "must support ... up to 63bits ... or the limit of your language", so `Int` should be fine. If you want to keep it, move it to `map`, i.e. your old version of `foldl1` and `map(fromIntegral.fromEnum)`.

Comment: @nimi OP posted a comment here (since deleted), asking if this supported 63 bits, so I assumed that was his intent. Beats me.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 65 bytes

**53 bytes code + 12 for `-Mbigint -p`.**

Thanks to @[Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada) for saving me 13 bytes!

```pl
$_=unpack"B*";say(0+"0b$_"),s/^0+//,y/10/01/while$_>0
```

Fairly straightforward approach, only different to most of these is that the number is stored as binary and printed out in decimal. I'm sure it can be improved, perhaps with storing details in an array. `-Mbigint` is a bit inconvenient but necessary.

#### Usage

```
echo -n 'Inf' | perl -Mbigint -pE'$_=unpack"B*";say(0+"0b$_"),s/^0+//,y/10/01/while$_>0'
4812390
3576217
618086
430489
93798
37273
28262
4505
3686
409
102
25
6
1
0
```

```
echo -n 'Infinity' | perl -Mbigint -pE'$_=unpack"B*";say(0+"0b$_"),s/^0+//,y/10/01/while$_>0'
5291279215216915577
3932092821637860230
679593196789527673
473328307817319302
103132444486104185
40982743589751686
31074850448176249
4953946570787718
4053252683953273
450346943417222
112603010004089
28134478351238
7049893737593
1746199284614
452823970937
96931842950
40507110521
28212366214
6147372153
2442562438
1852404857
295078790
241792121
26643334
6911097
1477510
619641
428934
95353
35718
29817
2950
1145
902
121
6
1
0
```

Comment: Unpack my friend, unpack! `perl -Mbigint -lpE'$_=unpack"B*";say(0+"0b$_"),s/^0+//,y/10/01/while$_>0'` (I have no idea how to use *unpack* usually, I just got lucky when googling how to convert a string to binary ;-) )

Comment: Ahhh, I always forget about `unpack` the syntax always blows my mind! I'll update, thank you!

Comment: There is [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) that should help... I've read the first 10 line dozens of time, but I should really take the time to read the rest!

Comment: @Dada I'm sure I've read it many times, it just never stays in... Thanks again -13 is no small feat! I had to switch to `echo -n` is the only other change.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
.usi!MjN2 2C
```

A program that takes input of a quoted string and prints the result as a list of integers.

[Verify all test cases](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.usi%21MjN2+2C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Inf%22%0A%22Infinity%22&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
.usi!MjN2 2C  Program. Input: Q
           C  Convert Q to an integer by code-points using base-256 (implicit input)
.u            Apply the following function A(N) until a repeat occurs, storing the results
              in a list:
      jN2       Convert to binary as a list
    !M          Map negation over the above
   i      2     Convert from binary to integer
  s             Integer (Converts final False to 0)
              Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>117</s> 115 bytes

Saving 2 bytes thanks to Cyoce.

Assumes input enclosed in quotes, e.g. `"Inf"`

```python
s=input()
n=sum(ord(s[-i-1])<<i*8for i in range(len(s)))
while n:
 print n;k,m=n,1
 while k:k/=2;m*=2
 n^=m-1
print 0
```

`m` counts up to the highest digit, so `m-1` is a XOR mask to perform the desired operation. The longest part is converting the input into the initial bit sequence.

Example:

```python
"Inf"
4812390
3576217
618086
430489
93798
37273
28262
4505
3686
409
102
25
6
1
0

"Infinity"
5291279215216915577
3932092821637860230
679593196789527673
473328307817319302
103132444486104185
40982743589751686
31074850448176249
4953946570787718
4053252683953273
450346943417222
112603010004089
28134478351238
7049893737593
1746199284614
452823970937
96931842950
40507110521
28212366214
6147372153
2442562438
1852404857
295078790
241792121
26643334
6911097
1477510
619641
428934
95353
35718
29817
2950
1145
902
121
6
1
0
```

Comment: You can replace `-i-1` with `~i`

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>99</s> 95 bytes

```
x=int.from_bytes(bytes(input(),'utf-8'),'big')
while x:print(x);x^=2**x.bit_length()-1
print(0)
```

Main idea is to convert string to bytes to to number. Each iteration print the output and XOR with all 1s to progress towards zero.

Comment: You don't need parentheses around `2**x.bit_length()-1`. Order of operations for power and subtraction are higher than xor. Also, that `while` can be on a single line.

Comment: Write the while loop on one line (remove the newline and indent)

Comment: Try starting the program with `P=print` and then using `P()` instead of `print()`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> <s>100</s> <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 65 bytes

*19 bytes saved thanks to @WayneConrad!

15 Bytes saved thanks to @philomory!

1 byte saved thanks to @LeeW!*

```rb
p n=$*[0].unpack('B*')[0].to_i(2)
p n^=2**n.bit_length-1while n>0
```

Takes input via command line arguments.

Inspired by @JimmyJohnson's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98295/41042)

Comment: You may be able to save a few characters by replacing `i.to_s(2).rjust 8,'0'` with `"%08b"%i`

Comment: Also, I think `inject(:+)` can be replaced with `join`

Comment: @WayneConrad thanks for the help! Not sure how I forgot about those

Comment: Glad I could help!  Thank you for teaching me the #bit_length method, which I didn't know about.

Comment: @WayneConrad it's relatively new. I had to install ruby 2.2 to make it work

Comment: Using `gsub` is slightly shorter than using `bytes`. Also, you can shave a few bytes off by doing this as a function instead of getting command line input.

Comment: @LeeW Wrapping it in a `->s{}` lambda takes two more bytes. How would I use `gsub`?

Comment: Instead of `s.bytes.map{|i|"%08b"%i}.join`, you can do `s.gsub(/./){|c|"%08b"%c.ord}`. It should be a byte shorter.

Comment: Switching to `unpack` followed by `[0]` rather than messing with `gsub` will save 11 bytes. Switching to `$*[0]` instead of `gets.chop` (using a command line argument instead of console input) will save another 9, first line becomes `p n=$*[0].unpack('B*')[0].to_i(2)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Labyrinth%20Labyrinth), <strike>104</strike> 103 bytes

```
'  )25 }_';:_';_2/;{
''', 6 2 1   1   { (
 ' | / _ _   _}*2_ $
 * _ :!\ }2_\     !:
 652       @'''''''
```

[Try it Online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=JyAgKTI1IH1fJzs6Xyc7XzIvO3sKJycnLCA2IDIgMSAgIDEgICB7ICgKICcgfCAvIF8gXyAgIF99KjJfICQKICogXyA6IVwgfTJfXCAgICAgIDoKIDY1MiAgICAgICBAJycnJycnJyE&input=SW5m)

### Explanation:

[image: Color-coded image of source code]

The instruction pointer starts at the top-left most non-wall character (walls include spaces and any letter except `v`).

#### Orange:

This loop gets the input one character at a time as an ASCII code, adding it to the current value and multiplying the current value by 256.

- `'` No-op
- `,` Push the ascii code of the next input char to the top of the stack or -1 if EOF. At this point if input was received, the code will turn right (moving down) because the top of the stack is potive. Otherwise it will turn left because the top of the stack is negative.
- `|` Pop the top two items from the stack and push the result of a bitwise OR.
- `_` Push zero
- `256` Each digit seen pops `x` and pushes `x*10+digit`. So this combined with the push zero previous push 256 to the top of the stack.
- `*` Pop `y`, pop `x`, push `x*y`. At this point since the top of the stack is positive the code will turn right to continue around the loop.

#### Blue:

- `)` Increment the top of the stack. When the end of input is reached, the code will turn left to get to this point with a -1 on the stack which will get incremented to zero.
- `256` Having the top of the stack 0 allows us to push this 256.
- `/` Pop `y`, pop `x` push `x/y` (integer division). Since we were multiplying the input by 256 each loop, we need to revert the last multiplication.
- `:` Duplicate the top of the stack so we have a copy of the current value for later.
- `!` Pop the top of the stack and print the integer value to STDOUT.
- `\` Print a new line.
- `_2` Push a two to the top of the stack.
- `}` Move the top of the stack to the top of the auxiliary stack.

#### Red:

This loop flips the bits of the current value by XOR with a particular value calculated in the inner (green) loop. It then outputs the current value and exits the program if the current value is zero.

- `_` Push zero (control flow).
- `;` Discard the top of the stack (control flow).
- `:` Duplicate the current value. The copy will be used to calculate the XOR.
- `_` Push zero (control flow).
- (Green loop)
- `$` Pop `y`, pop `x`, Push `x XOR y`.
- `:!` Duplicate the current value and print the integer representation.
- If the current value is 0, we continue straight into the `@` and terminate.
- `\` Print a new line.
- `_2}` Push 2 and move to the aux stack.
- `_1` Push 1 (control flow).

#### Green:

This loop calculates the value by which we need to XOR the current value. This is done by repeatedly doubling the top of the auxiliary stack while halving a copy of the current value on the stop of the main stack until it reaches 0.

- `_` Push zero (control flow).
- `;` Discard the current value which is only used to enforce control flow.
- `_2` Push 2 in order to halve the current value.
- `/` Divide
- `{` Move the top of the aux stack to the top of the main stack.
- `_2*` Double the top of the stack
- `}` Move the top of the main stack back to the aux stack.
- `_1` Push one for control flow.
- After exiting the loop:
- `;` Discard the left over zero from calculating the XOR.
- `{` Move the calculated XOR to the main stack.
- `(` Subtract one from XOR value.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 158 bytes

```
for($a=-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{([int][convert]::ToString(+$_,2)).ToString('0'*8)});$a){[convert]::ToInt64($a,2);$a=$a.TrimStart('0')-split0-replace1,0-join1}
```

Yeah, so, converting bases in PowerShell [is really sucky](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=base+user%3A42963+is%3Aa). And we get to do it twice here.

OK, so this is just a `for` loop on `$a` -- i.e., we loop so long as `$a` exists. We'll eventually reach an empty string (which is falsey), so that's how we'll terminate.

The setup of the loop, `$a=-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{([int][convert]::ToString(+$_,2)).ToString('0'*8)})`, takes the input `$args[0]`, casts it as a `char`-array, and loops through each character. We use the .NET `[convert]::ToString(int,base)` to convert each to a binary string. However, that doesn't include leading zeros, so we need to re-cast that string as an `[int]` and call *its* `.ToString()` method with `8` zeros as the mask. Then those strings are encapsulated in parens and `-join`ed together, then saved into `$a`.

Inside the loop, we `[convert]::ToInt64(string,base)` to convert the binary number to a decimal number. That gets left on the pipeline and is subsequently flushed when the loop resets (and therefore implicitly printed). The next section performs the calculations -- we `.TrimStart()` to remove any leading zeros, `-split0` to split on zeros and get a `string`-array of `1`s, `-replace` those ones with zeros, and finally `-join` the array back together with `1`s. Then, the loop begins again.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\count-down-from-infinity.ps1 'PPCG'
1347437383
800046264
273695559
263175352
5260103
3128504
1065799
1031352
17223
15544
839
184
71
56
7
0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 18 bytes

```
q256b0{_p2b:!2bj}j
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cTI1NmIwe19wMmI6ITJian1q&input=)

```
q256b   e# read printable ascii to integer
0       e# value for terminal case
{       e# recursive function
  _p    e#   print current number
  2b    e#   create binary representation with no leading zeros
  :!    e#   flip bits
  2b    e#   convert binary back to integer
  j     e#   recursive call
}j      e# end
```

***NOTE:*** The old 16 byte version didn't behave correctly with empty strings:

```
q256b{_p2b:!2b}h
```

Also, thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for suggesting `p` which saves 1 byte over `N\` putting newlines into the stack.

Comment: `_p2b:!2b` saves a byte. Also, you should use `l`; `r` will fail if the input contains spaces.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, though this now makes me worry if a empty string is an issue.

Comment: Right. `q` will work correctly with empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 24 bytes

```
256-.&.#:^:*^:a:@#.a.&i.
```

Explanation will come later!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Permalink for the interested: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krByNRMV09NT9kqzkorzirRykFZL1FPLVPvf2pyRr5CmoK6Z16aOhcSJzMvs6RS/T8A "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 116 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding. Line 5 contains non-printable bytes. It's `` T`\x00-\xFF ``.

```
-2`
±
s{`±(.)
$&$1
}T`-`_o`±.
[^±]+
$.&
±
 
\d+
$*
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
 

{*(`1
01
+`10
011
^0+

)M`1
^0+

T`01`10
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LTJgCsKxCnN7YMKxKC4pCiQmJDEKfVRgAS1_YF9vYMKxLgpbXsKxXSsKJC4mCsKxCiAKXGQrCiQqCitgKDErKVwxCiR7MX0wCjAxCjEKIAoKeyooYDEKMDEKK2AxMAowMTEKXjArCgopTWAxCl4wKwoKVGAwMWAxMA&input=SW4)

Don't try this with input longer than two characters. (It times out using the online interpreter.) We gotta convert the binary to unary before decimal. :D

Unfortunately, there's a trailing zero and linefeed, but I decided to assume that was okay because the output is still correct.

**Explanation**

```
-2`         # Convert ASCII to decimal (ord)
±
s{`±(.)
$&$1
}T`-`_o`±.
[^±]+
$.&
±
 
\d+         # Decimal to binary
$*
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
 

{*(`1       # Loop; Loop print and undo; Convert binary to unary
01
+`10
011
^0+

)M`1        # Unary to decimal; End print and undo
^0+         # Remove leading zeros

T`01`10     # Flip bits; (implicit loop end)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>147</s> <s>135</s> <s>133</s> <s>125</s> <s>122</s> <s>121</s> <s>117</s> <s>115</s> 103 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Cyoce!*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Cyoce and @cleblanc!*

*Saved 12 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*

```c
i,n;main(p,v)char**v;{while(*v[1])i=i*256+*v[1]++;for(;printf("%d\n",n=i),i;i^=p-1)for(p=2;n/=2;)p*=2;}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
int i;
int main (c,v) {
    char**v;
    while (*v[1]) /* put first command line argument into i as binary */
        i = i*256 + *v[1]++;
    while (i != 0) { 
        printf("%d\n",i);
        int p = 2,n = i;
        while (n /= 2) /* calculate smallest power of 2 > i */
            p *= 2;
        i ^= p - 1; /* flip bits */
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can leave out the `int` declarations

Comment: You can also save a byte by converting the last `while` loop into a `for` loop

Comment: And you can change `while(1)` to `for(;;)`

Comment: @Cyoce I tried removing `int` declarations everywhere and got `gcc -std=89` errors. But  thanks for the `for(;;)` tip. I'll keep on trying to remove the `int` declarations :)))

Comment: sorry, I didn't test it. I think it will work if you move them to the top (`i;main(c,v)char**v;{...}`). On mobile right now so I can't be sure

Comment: @Cyoce On mobile too. Will test your ideas tomorrow. Thanks so much, I've been trying to get a byte or two down for ages :)))

Comment: Can you use the same technique you used for `i` to save on the `int` declaration for `p` and `n`?

Comment: @Cyoce Unfortunately that only trades 4 bytes `int ` for 4 bytes `,p,n`

Comment: I think you can re-write the signature for main as `main(c,v)char**v;`

Comment: @cleblanc Tried that and `gcc` with `-std=c89` wouldn't compile it.

Comment: @Noodle9 try -std=c99 that works for me.  I think it's the default for my compiler `gcc (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)`

Comment: @Noodle9 it works for me with just `gcc`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 70 bytes

```
λ cat inf.rb
n,=$*[0].unpack 'B*';loop{p n.to_i(2);n.tr!('10','01').sub!(/^0*/,'')}
λ ruby inf.rb Hello
310939249775
788572378000
310939249775
238816564112
36061342831
32658133904
1701604463
445879184
90991727
43226000
23882863
9671568
7105647
1282960
814191
234384
27759
5008
3183
912
111
16
15
0
inf.rb:1:in `block in <main>': undefined method `sub!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from inf.rb:1:in `loop'
        from inf.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

The program exits with an exception after completing, but my understanding is that that is fine as long as the error output goes to STDERR rather than STDOUT (which it does).

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>129</s> <s>120</s> <s>117</s> <s>110</s> <s>107</s> 105 Bytes

```
long long i,m,n;f(char*v){for(;*v;i<<=8,i+=*v++);for(;printf("%llu,",i),n=i;i^=m-1)for(m=2;n>>=1;m<<=1);}
```

Tested with

```
main (int c, char**v) {
    f(v[1]);
}
```

output

```
5291279215216915577,3932092821637860230,679593196789527673,473328307817319302,103132444486104185,40982743589751686,31074850448176249,4953946570787718,4053252683953273,450346943417222,112603010004089,28134478351238,7049893737593,1746199284614,452823970937,96931842950,40507110521,28212366214,6147372153,2442562438,1852404857,295078790,241792121,26643334,6911097,1477510,619641,428934,95353,35718,29817,2950,1145,902,121,6,1,0,
```

Comment: I think you can move `i=0` to the declaration of `i` and leave the initialization section of the `for` loop blank

Comment: @Cyoce The function needs to work each time it's called and since `i` is implicit global int it needs to be initialized every time f(...) is called.

Comment: @Cyoce You were right after all.  The function doesn't exit until `i` is zero again so it's still re-useable.

Comment: [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY1NCoMwEEb3nmIQCvmToqvCmAP0DKUFCcQOmFGCDRTx7GmazVt8fI/nutm5nJeVZ6ggEwyjF@49RZXk4dcoUCUkbVXSWtI42hvWdYvEuxftZVk@pjUkDVtCetnQ9fL/CHZAvhYEZQeJZw4TMYhigTNQCyUBRwPgRXr0T4nNmfOdPTHt3x8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>360</s> 359 bytes

```
using w=System.Console;using q=System.Convert;s={System.Func<int,int,string>S=q.ToString;string t="",f="";for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)t+=i>0?S(s[i],2).PadLeft(8,'0'):S(s[i],2);w.WriteLine(q.ToInt64(t,2).ToString());while(t!="0"){f="";foreach(var n in t)f+=n=='0'?'1':'0';t=f.TrimStart(new char[]{'0'});t+=t==""?"0":"";w.WriteLine(q.ToInt64(t,2).ToString());}};
```

Full program:

```
using w = System.Console;
using q = System.Convert;

class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Action<string> b = s =>
        {
            System.Func<int,int,string> S = q.ToString;
            string t = "", f = ""; // Var does not work here
            for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                t += i > 0 ? S(s[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0') : S(s[i], 2);
            w.WriteLine(q.ToInt64(t, 2).ToString());
            while(t != "0")
            {
                f = "";
                foreach (var n in t) f += n== '0' ? '1' : '0';
                t = f.TrimStart(new char[] { '0' });
                t += t == "" ? "0" : "";
                w.WriteLine(q.ToInt64(t, 2).ToString());
            }
        };

        b("Inf");
        b("Infinity");
        w.Read(); // prevent close in VS
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't do C#, but can `var t="";var f="";` be `var t="",f=""` instead? Saves 5 bytes.

Comment: @corsiKa Yeah I tried that but it gave me an error, I guess cause it's var and not string.

Comment: Actually, string does save one byte, so I guess I'll do it that way.

Comment: Also can you make a z variable for zero to save those nasty quotes?

Comment: Just tried, it actually raises the bytecount because I can't replace both the string "0" and char '0' :(